# ASP.NET Web API authorization has been denied for this request even is token has not expired

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, owin

I'm facing an authentication issue abruptly.

Even if the token is not expired, after some idle session(may be 30 minutes or so)authorization fails for requests on the page for API calls.

This is my code for `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)`:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

User gets a status code: 401 and error:

> Authorization has been denied for this request

Please help.